# jQuery dynamic event handler error

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, extension-methods, jquery-events

I have made an event handler for a DOM element that is created dynamically, but am receiving an error. I made a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akkvbu0u/2/), but the error is not occurring here, only in my application.

I have included two event handlers, `change` and `click`. The `change` is the only one I care about: I only included the `click` to make sure that an event handler on a dynamic DOM element would work.

If you don't want to look at the demo, here's the basic code (I am using a Word and Character Counter plugin which uses the `.counter()` method, which you can find at `http://qwertypants.github.io/jQuery-Word-and-Character-Counter-Plugin/` ):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>//plugin</script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myTextArea").counter();
            //Below, my selector is called myTextArea_count because the plugin creates a <span> with an id
            //equal to the id of the element it is counting for, with "_count" appended.
            $(document).on("change", "#myTextArea_count", function() {
                $("<p>Count changed</p>").appendTo("#myTextArea_counter");
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#myTextArea_count", function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
                    $this.css("color", "orange");
                }
                else {
                    $this.css("color", "black");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [screenshot](http://s8.postimg.org/9oy06j8k5/2015_01_23_18_02_21.png) of my very long, repeating error in Chrome.

### Here's the kicker...

The `.on("click")` event works *fine* for me in my application, while the `.on("change")`, which I am triggering manually from my extension of `$.text()`, does not, even though it works in the JSFiddle.

Does anyone know why this error is taking place?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you try renaming `change` to a custom name? Doesn't make much sense to me to use a form control event name on a content element

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle Demo**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/akkvbu0u/4/
```

**Working sample**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>


    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="word-and-character-counter.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#myTextArea").counter({ count: 'up',
    goal: 10});
            //Below, my selector is called myTextArea_count because the plugin creates a <span> with an id
            //equal to the id of the element it is counting for, with "_count" appended.
            $(document).on("change", "#myTextArea_count", function() {
                $("<p>Count changed</p>").appendTo("#myTextArea_counter");
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#myTextArea_count", function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
                    $this.css("color", "orange");
                }
                else {
                    $this.css("color", "black");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

**Note** : i have used  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwertypants/jQuery-Word-and-Character-Counter-Plugin/master/word-and-character-counter.js plugin not minified version and there are no errors in chrome console also

Comment: have used full version  url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwertypants/jQuery-Word-and-Character-Counter-Plugin/master/word-and-character-counter.js